# How do I efficiently track the history of a tensorflow tensor?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

Is this pattern of using a `TensorArray` an efficient way of keeping track of a tensor's history?  Is everything inside the inner loop done on the GPU without transmitting anything to the CPU?   How can I verify this?

```
import tensorflow as tf


with tf.device('/device:GPU:0'):
    @tf.function
    def f(x, y):
        return y, x + y

    x_array = tf.TensorArray(tf.float32, 0, dynamic_size=True,
                             clear_after_read=False)
    y_array = tf.TensorArray(tf.float32, 0, dynamic_size=True,
                             clear_after_read=False)

    x = tf.Variable([1.0])
    y = tf.Variable([1.0])
    x_array.write(0, x)
    y_array.write(0, y)

    for i in tf.range(10):
        x = x_array.read(i)
        y = y_array.read(i)
        new_x, new_y = f(x, y)
        x_array.write(i + 1, new_x)
        y_array.write(i + 1, new_y)

    print(x_array.stack())
    print(y_array.stack())
```

This is what I'm actually trying to do, but it doesn't even run:

```
import tensorflow as tf


with tf.device('/device:GPU:0'):
    @tf.function
    def f(x, y):
        return y, x + y

    @tf.function
    def g(n):
        for i in tf.range(n):
            x = x_array.read(i)
            y = y_array.read(i)
            new_x, new_y = f(x, y)
            x_array.write(i + 1, new_x)
            y_array.write(i + 1, new_y)

    x_array = tf.TensorArray(tf.float32, 0, dynamic_size=True,
                             clear_after_read=False)
    y_array = tf.TensorArray(tf.float32, 0, dynamic_size=True,
                             clear_after_read=False)

    x = tf.Variable([1.0])
    y = tf.Variable([1.0])
    x_array.write(0, x)
    y_array.write(0, y)

    g(tf.constant(10))

    print(x_array.stack())
    print(y_array.stack())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can fix your second snippet:

```
import tensorflow as tf

with tf.device('/device:GPU:0'):
    @tf.function
    def f(x, y):
        return y, x + y

    @tf.function
    def g(x, y, n):
        x_array = tf.TensorArray(tf.float32, n + 1, dynamic_size=False,
                                 clear_after_read=True)
        y_array = tf.TensorArray(tf.float32, n + 1, dynamic_size=False,
                                 clear_after_read=True)
        x_array = x_array.write(0, x)
        y_array = y_array.write(0, y)
        for i in range(n):
            x, y = f(x, y)
            x_array = x_array.write(i + 1, x)
            y_array = y_array.write(i + 1, y)
        return x_array.stack(), y_array.stack()


    x = tf.Variable([1.0])
    y = tf.Variable([1.0])

    x_hist, y_hist = g(x, y, tf.constant(10))

    print(x_hist)
    # tf.Tensor(
    # [[ 1.]
    #  [ 1.]
    #  [ 2.]
    #  [ 3.]
    #  [ 5.]
    #  [ 8.]
    #  [13.]
    #  [21.]
    #  [34.]
    #  [55.]
    #  [89.]], shape=(11, 1), dtype=float32)
    print(y_hist)
    # tf.Tensor(
    # [[  1.]
    #  [  2.]
    #  [  3.]
    #  [  5.]
    #  [  8.]
    #  [ 13.]
    #  [ 21.]
    #  [ 34.]
    #  [ 55.]
    #  [ 89.]
    #  [144.]], shape=(11, 1), dtype=float32)
```

There were a few issues. A `tf.function` should take its input as arguments, not from the global scope. You can make the tensor arrays within the function, and you can make them fixed-size and with clear-after-read, since you are not going to use them after. But it is important that you assign the result of each `write` operation to the array variable, since that will make it into "the tensor array after writing". You do not need to use `tf.range` in the loop. And the "history" array can be filled more effectively simply by writing the result of each iteration, instead of reading again from the array.

About the GPU, since everything is within a `tf.device` context, it will all be allocated and run on the GPU, if something cannot run there there would be an error, so as long as everything runs it should be fine.

Comment: Thanks!  But now that you're passing in `x`, and `y`, I'm worried because I actually have, say, a hundred such variables and TensorArrays.  I was hoping to put them into a dictionary or object.  What's the idiomatic TensorFlow way of doing this?  Would I put them into a keras layer?

Comment: @NeilG I don't know about your actual use case so I can't tell for sure, but I think it's not very common to have hundreds of independent variables, but rather variables with hundreds (or more) of values. But anyway, I suppose you could have all those in an object as an attribute. However, I'm not sure if `tf.function` supports iterating collections of tensors, as I'm getting errors when I try to use that...

Comment: Thanks for taking a look.  I ran into the same problem, but a bit more investigation suggests that I should probably use `AbstractRNNCell` to implement an object whose state changes with each iteration.  https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/RELEASE.md

Comment: @NeilG Ahh I think I understand better now, thank you for the feedback.